# Flight ticket combination only available through agency

Tags: short-connections, covid-19, cdg, travel-agency

I'd like to fly within Europe in these troubled days.
Air France has a good combination (with a short connection of 50 minutes in CDG, with change of terminal).
However, AF websites doesn't sell the combination. It does sell the two legs of the journeys separately, however.
The combination is only available through opodo and gotogate.

Should I trust buying through them?
I am concerned that I could be not covered about the short connection with terminal transfer, in case complications (e.g. due to COVID) arise: my final destination is not France, so this could be dangerous.

Opodo says "Connection covered by Air France": do you think this is reliable?

Any advice welcome.

Comment: you will probably be able to book it from AF by _calling_ them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is reliable, I have booked through both opodo and gotogate, no issues what-so-ever. I have also had a missed connection in CDG, at which AirFrance gave me food vouchers and re-booked me onto the next flight. It's quite common for airlines not to sell tickets together if you are in doubt buy the tickets on AF seperately.